# Where do I register HttpContextBase for StructureMap Nested Container?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, inversion-of-control, structuremap, structuremap4

I am new to IoC and installed Nuget Package `StructureMap.MVC5` into my MVC project.
I am trying to register the following:
`For<HttpContextBase>().Use(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))`

Based on what I am reading I need to reference that in the Nested Container and I see a reference to the Nested Container in the `StructureMapDependencyScope.cs` file that came with the package.  However, I do not know where/how to register this HttpContextBase with it.

I tried registering it from the `StructuremapMvc.cs` file like this:

```
public static class StructuremapMvc {

        public static StructureMapDependencyScope StructureMapDependencyScope { get; set; }

        public static void End() {
            StructureMapDependencyScope.Dispose();
        }

        public static void Start() {
            IContainer container = IoC.Initialize();
            StructureMapDependencyScope = new StructureMapDependencyScope(container);

            StructureMapDependencyScope.CreateNestedContainer();
            StructureMapDependencyScope.CurrentNestedContainer.Configure(x =>
            {
                x.For<IUserIdentity>().Use<CurrentUser>();
                x.For<HttpContextBase>().Use(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
            });

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(StructureMapDependencyScope);
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(StructureMapScopeModule));
        }
    }
```

But that's not working.  I am getting an error from the `HttpContext` property inside of `StructureMapDependencyScope.cs`.

Comment: Could you update your question with the error message you're receiving? And where is `StructuremapMvc.Start()` being called?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should contain class called `DefaultRegistry`, you can put registration in there. Nested container will automatically inherit this registration from the parent.